# Why is this my simple cache not working?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I have a chunk of code I wrote

```
private int CountChangeOptions(int[] coins, int j, int N)
{   
    if(j == 0)
        return 0;
    if(N == 0)
        return 1;
    if(j == 1)
        return N % coins[0] == 0 ? 1 : 0;

    int sum = 0;
    int k = coins[j - 1];
    for(int i = N; i >= 0; i -= k)
    {
        sum += CountChangeOptions(coins, j - 1, i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

that is evaluating correctly (though not fast enough). Since `CountChangeOptions(coins, x, y)` for most `coins` will in the course of the algorithm will be called several times with the same `x`,`y` I decided to implement a caching strategy

```
private int CountChangeOptions(int[] coins, int j, int N)
{   
    if(j == 0)
        return 0;
    if(N == 0)
        return 1;
    if(j == 1)
        return N % coins[0] == 0 ? 1 : 0;

    int sum = 0;
    int k = coins[j - 1];
    for(int i = N; i >= 0; i -= k)
    {
        sum += CountOrGetFromCache(coins, j - 1, i);
    }
    return sum;
}

private int CountOrGetFromCache(int[] coins, int j, int i)
{
    if(_cache[j, i] == null)
    {
       _cache[j, i] = CountChangeOptions(coins, j, i);
    }
    return (int)_cache[j, i];
}
```

where `_cache` is an `int?[][]` that has been previously set with `_cache = new int[N+1, N+1]`. However this is now failing some of the test cases. Any idea why?

Comment: For what inputs do you get incorrect output? Have you tried debugging this? Oh, and you may want to use more descriptive variable names - names like `j`, `i`, `N` and `k` aren't very helpful when you need to track down bugs in an algorithm.

Comment: If your `coins` array changes, then the cached values will be invalid.

Comment: How are you initializing a `int?[][]` using `new int[N+1, N+1]`?  That results in an error for me:  `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[*,*]' to 'int?[][]'`.  Can you  please show the declarations for `_cache` and how exactly you are initializing it?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that I see is that the _cache variable is incorrectly initialized to

```
_cache = new int[N+1, N+1]
```

instead of

```
_cache = new int[coins.Length+1, N+1]
```

Other than that, both solutions are functionally same. I don't believe that there is a functional test case which works for the first (slow) implementation and fails for the second implementation.

I am guessing that you are using some website like HackerRank or its like, and the first solution probably times-out, giving you the feeling that it works and the second being faster does not time-out but produces the incorrect result.